# Items do not appear in $ when they become visible after a <template if=""> condition has been met

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

How do you handle this simple thing?

In my element that handles commenting, I get the inputs with:

CoreInput get name => $['name'];
  CoreInput get comment => $['comment'];

But this whole commenting area is wrapped with an if="{{app.user != null}}", so when the element first loads, those getters = null because app.user is only determined after the app loads and the element is attached.

Hence, when going to the item I'm commenting on directly, it triggers an error when adding a comment. Because the element was attached before app.user evaluated to true.

When coming from a different page/element, where we already have app.user, everything's fine.

When I move those definitions to the addComment() method itself (which is only available when we have app.user)...

CoreInput name = $['name'];
  CoreInput comment = $['comment'];

...same thing! Switching from $ to querySelector, same thing.

(Man, all this stuff is really getting in the way. We need best practices docs for Polymer!)

Comment: Dynamically added comment is not part of the `$`. See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/642#issuecomment-52534364

Comment: Thanks! I figured that out in the meantime. Funny, I'm using `CoreInput name = shadowRoot.querySelector('#name');` as per that issue, but that too is an "anti-pattern". So, what is the right pattern? I am using conditional blocks of code, but where can I find some best practice docs or code that teach me the right way?

Comment: See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding. We recommend putting an id on a container element and using that with node finding and querySelector.

Comment: Do you agree w/ the answer I just posted?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, $ is a simple Map populated right after the template is first "stamped", and so does not contain items added dynamically, such as is the case within a template conditional.

The best solution was to think about it a wholly different way: bind the form values to an observable Map, called theData for example.

This is nicely explained here: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#binding-data

We then have access to the values regardless of if the form elements are present – if they're not, the Map has set default (blank) values. (At any rate, we're likely only referencing these values when we know the form elements exist.)

```
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable Map theData = toObservable({
    'name': '',
    'comment': ''
  });
  ...

  addComment(Event e, var detail, Element target) {
    e.preventDefault();

    String name = theData['name'];
    name = name.trim();
    String comment = theData['comment'];
    comment = comment.trim();
    ...
```

Voila! Two way data binding between the form and the Dart code, and it all feels Polymer fresh.